# Disabling "You are joining a meeting" voice when PSTN call joins Skype for Business meeting

Tags: skype-for-business, ucma

Is there any way to disable "You are now joining the meeting" voice message when a user calling from PSTN joins a conference?

I tried to change the message following this blog: http://www.skypeadmin.com/2014/10/06/customize-dialin-conference-attendant-prompts-audio/ but it didn't work in Skype for Business Server 2015.

I am working on a UCMA Application which takes calls from PSTN number and joins them in a meeting on Skype for Business.

**Edit:**

The message is heard by the person who dials into the system using PSTN number. We tried running `Set-CsDialInConferencingConfiguration` command but it didn't work. The application joins the caller and a user in a conference call. The call is first put on hold, then a user is assigned to that call and the application creates a conference call between them. This is the point where the caller hears a voice saying **"You are now joining the meeting."**

Answer (score 0):

As you didn´t specify what your application should do and if you expect the announcement in your application or on the user side its not totally clear what you mean. What you can is to control some of those "voice announcements" via [Set-CsDialInConferencingConfiguration](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg425825.aspx).

For example:

EnableNameRecording:

> Determines whether or not users are asked to record their name before
>   entering the conference. Set to True to enable name recording; set to
>   False to bypass name recording. The default value is True.

EntryExitAnnouncementsEnabledByDefault:

> If set to True announcements will be played each time a participant
>   enters or exits a conference. If set to False (the default value),
>   entry and exit announcements will not be played.

EntryExitAnnouncementsType:

> Indicates the action taken by the system any time a participant enters
>   or leaves a conference. (Announcements are made only if the
>   EntryExitAnnouncementsEnabledByDefault is set to True.) Valid values
>   are: UseNames. The person's name is announced any time her or she
>   enters or leaves a conference (for example, "Ken Myer is exiting the
>   conference"). ToneOnly. A tone is played any time a participant enters
>   or leaves a conference.The default value is UseNames.

Comment: The message is heard by the person who dials into the system using PSTN number. We tried running that command but it didn't work. The application joins the user dialing and a user in a conference call. The call is first put on hold, then a user is assigned to that call and the application creates a conference call between them.

Comment: I edited my question with more details. Thanks for your answer.